# How Get relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net

Get picture file  relative path from diffrent location.
my Address pic file like
~/Uploads/Picture/Commodities/1390/11/TumbDesert.jpg

Comment: Using what language? This really needs more detail as to what tools you're using.

Comment: What are you using? php, C#? I think you're going to have to add more detail if you expect a useful response.

Comment: i have a picture in 

x.com/Uploads/Picture/Commodities/1390/11/TumbDesert.jpg

my page in x.com/Public/page.aspx

i want get picture relative path from page.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these methods to generate urls relative to pages that you execute them within:

```
this.Page.ResolveUrl
this.Page.ResolveClientUrl


this.Page.ResolveUrl("~/Uploads/Picture/Commodities/1390/11/TumbDesert.jpg");
this.Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Uploads/Picture/Commodities/1390/11/TumbDesert.jpg");
```